# How to optimize huge left join in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

I have two tables in my mysql database:

**1) Videos**

```
+----+--------+----------+------+----------+
| id | title  | category | year | director |
+----+--------+----------+------+----------+
|  1 | Title1 | Cat1     | 2021 | A.K.     |
|  2 | Title2 | Cat2     | 2020 | B.C.     |
|  3 | Title3 | Cat3     | 2000 | E.A.     |
+----+--------+----------+------+----------+
```

**2) Videos_insights**

```
+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
| video_id |    date    | views | likes | dislikes | shares |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
|        1 | 2021-03-20 |    13 |     2 |        3 |      1 |
|        1 | 2021-03-19 |    35 |     1 |        3 |      3 |
|        1 | 2021-03-18 |    68 |     5 |        6 |      5 |
|        1 | 2021-03-15 |    86 |     3 |        0 |      1 |
|        2 | 2021-02-13 |   234 |    15 |        1 |     34 |
|        2 | 2021-02-12 |    55 |    15 |        2 |      4 |
|        2 | 2021-02-10 |   331 |   255 |        0 |      0 |
+----------+------------+-------+-------+----------+--------+
```

And I want to get videos that had between watched `2021-03-01` to `2021-03-31`. So the result table should look like this:

```
+--------+-------------------------------------------+
| title  |                date_range                 |
+--------+-------------------------------------------+
| Title1 | ["2021-03-20 - 2021-03-18", "2021-03-15"] |
+--------+-------------------------------------------+
```

In my MySQL database, I have about 100 000 videos and each video has about 100 video_insight.

1. What is the best way to achieve the result table?
2. How to optimize? I mean I do not want to make every GET request left join? It would take too long and my server will burn out.

Comment: . . If you want to optimize something, you should show the query you are using.  Otherwise, I just assume the question is how to get the results that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

I would express the dates individually:

```
select v.id, v.title,
       group_concat(date) as dates
from videos v join
     video_insights vi
     on vi.video_id = v.id
where vi.date >= '2021-03-01' and
      vi.date < '2021-04-01'
group by v.id;
```

Note that a `left join` is not appropriate because you are filtering the values.

If you *really* want to get the ranges, then you can use window functions with a gaps-and-islands approach:

```
select v.id, v.title, group_concat(date_range)
from videos v join
     (select vi.video_id,
             concat_ws(' - ', min(vi.date), nullif(max(date), min(date))) as date_range
      from (select vi.*,
                   dense_rank() over (partition by vi.video_id order by vi.date) as seqnum
            from video_insights vi
            where vi.date >= '2021-03-01' and
                  vi.date < '2021-04-01'
           ) vi
      group by vi.video_id, date - interval seqnum day
     ) vi
     on vi.video_id = v.id
group by v.id;
```

Comment: 1) Why you make a noninclusive date `< '2021-04-01'`? Isn't better to make `<= '2021-03-31`?
2) Do you know the answer to the second question? Maybe do some snapshots?

Comment: @mickris . . . It is better to use `<`.  This works regardless of whether or not the "date" has a time component.  It is just a good habit to prevent. unexpected errors.